# Variable 'c' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

Tags: c, ubuntu, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have searched and haven't really found and understood this error. It's weird that I only get the error for c, d, e and not for a and b or them all.

Program is about Dooubly Link List.

This happens when I compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -g -c program.c
```

Error part:

```
void try_mymem(int argc, char** argv) {
strategies strat;
void *a, *b, *c, *d, *e;
if (argc > 1)
    strat = strategyFromString(argv[1]);
else
    strat = First;

/* A simple example.
   Each algorithm should produce a different layout. */

initmem(strat, 500);

a = mymalloc(100);
b = mymalloc(100);
c = mymalloc(100);
myfree(b);
d = mymalloc(50);
myfree(a);
e = mymalloc(25);

print_memory();
print_memory_status();
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

They're not used, just like the compiler says. You assign but never read. `a` and `b` are used as arguments, the others are not.

Comment: But, isn't it this:
a = mymalloc(100);
b = mymalloc(100);
c = mymalloc(100);
myfree(b);
d = mymalloc(50);
myfree(a);
e = mymalloc(25);

Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: There's a difference between *assignment*, like `a = ...` and usage, like `f(a)`. The compiler is saying that you assign a lot of variables that are never used.